# How to filter out keys based on some pattern on Aerospike?

Tags: aerospike

i have millions of records on aerospike in namespace:set

```
keys are in this format: lastname/firstname/state/zip

example:
smith/john/fl/32817
smith/carla/tn/45125
brown/chris/tn/45125
```

> i want to get all keys which match with the pattern
> "*/chris/*/45125" or some other pattern and want to perform some
> operations on those resulting keys.

i can do a scan all to get all records and match the pattern with keys but that would be so time expensive. i have seen different posts but couldn't find a solution to this. how can i achieve this?

Answer (score 3):

According to: https://discuss.aerospike.com/t/how-to-apply-regex-search-on-primary-index-using-aerospike-golang-client/9909 (originally for Golang but the principle is the same):

> "With Expressions, it is possible to do regex search on Key, but as
> @meher said, you must store the key on the server. You can either
> store it via `sendKey` set to true, or you can also store in a record
> bin."

`sendKey` needs to be set to true because by default Aerospike doesn't store the key - it stores a digest which is a result of RIPEMD-160 hashing function on the key and the set name.

You can change the `sendKey` on the `Policy` you provide in the operation you execute.

Original link contains code examples in `Java` and `Golang`.